# Checking if dir exist via stat with path

Tags: c++, stat

This compiles, but I don't believe it is actually checking in the proper directory to see if the sub directory, which it is looking for, exists.

```
    cout<< "Welcome back, '" << account << "'!\n";
    if (bool account = S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
        cout<<"Please enter your password: ";
    }
    else {
        cout<< "There is no account by that name, please type NEW to create a new account.\n";
```

And so I am curious how would I set the file path in this example so that it checks in the parent directory. It is in the tree like so:

```
"home/user/Program/accounts/" + account
```

Comment: This makes no sense. `account` is a `bool`, and possibly something else. And we have no idea where `sb` comes from.

Comment: You've not shown the call to `stat()`, or enough declarations.  However, `stat()` takes a file path, which might be a full absolute path, or a simple file name (corresponding to a name in the current directory), or a multi-component relative path.  Your choice.  The main thing is to check that `stat()` succeeded, and not to look at the value in the `struct stat sb` unless the `stat()` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I had to rework this, Jonathan's help in directing me with his explanation of stat() helped quite a bit, but here is how I got it to work.

```
    cout<< "Welcome back, '" << account << "'!\n";
```

Prints Welcome back account name provided from previous code.

```
    struct stat sb;
```

Creates the structure of the stat and its variable name.

```
    if (stat(("/home/user/Account Program/accounts/"+account).c_str(),&sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
        cout<<"Please enter your password: ";
    }
```

The If check. stat( opens the stat call as structured above with the path starting ("home..." then I pass the dir I'm checking via +account and turing the null string created by +account into a proper string via ).c_str(). Then I check if it succeeded like so, == 0, and if it is a dir by S_ISDIR.

```
    else {
        cout<< "There is no account by that name, please type NEW to create a new account.\n";
    }
```

Here I provide an Else so that it prints something to let me know if it failed, or later on to be used in the loop that returns you to the start to either create an account or re-enter your account name.

I think that sums it up. I could have explained some of this incorrectly, but to the best of my knowledge that is how I understood it.